# Verifying user data sent to a smart contract

Tags: plutus

so i've got a fun idea to use an in game puzzle and the infinite solutions possible as a method to mine a coin. Essentially i want the gamer to create a system, and however long it runs for without falling apart will dictate how much currency is minted to reward the system. (kinda like earning in-game points, except i want it too be a crypto-token)

the slight catch is i'd like it too be a mobile game written in Unity, so i don't think i can verify the solution 'on-chain', but i also don't want someone to be able to just call a smart contract with "?duration=allTheTime" to mint all the monies fraudulently.

How would everyone else approach this? I've considered maybe a system of 'authorized accounts' that can do verification of submitted solutions, or somehow crowd sourcing the verification in a decentralized manner, but that stuff gets complicated fast. thoughts?

Edit: no idea why this question is being downvoted. I'd like to give a simpler example. giving out points in a game, and recording those on the blockchain.. "you chopped some wood, 2 points"... how to prevent fraud when the smart contract is publicly exposed to mint new points. store the private minting key IN-APP? (obviously not). help.